# du and ls report different directory size?

Tags: linux, ls, du

In trying to verify that a copy-operation completed successfully (or at least that it didn't skip any files), I ran `du -b` inside the source and destination directory and it showed a difference of about 100KB.

So, I went tracking down the difference and found one (of many) leaf-directory where `du` reports a difference in total size for the copy and the original.

The strange thing is that `ls -l` shows these directories as perfectly identical!

Here are the two outputs in the two different directories:

```
root@...:/local/.../DCIM/100___12# du -b
5286222389      .
root@...:/local/.../DCIM/100___12# ls -l --block-size=1
total 5292851200
-rwxr--r-- 1 markus markus   2167504 Aug  5  2013 IMG_0004.JPG
-rwxr--r-- 1 markus markus   2236594 Aug  5  2013 IMG_0005.JPG
...
```

vs.

```
root@...:/local_old/.../DCIM/100___12# du -b
5286226485      .
root@...:/local_old/.../DCIM/100___12# ls -l --block-size=1
total 5292851200
-rwxr--r-- 1 markus markus   2167504 Aug  5  2013 IMG_0004.JPG
-rwxr--r-- 1 markus markus   2236594 Aug  5  2013 IMG_0005.JPG
...
```

Note how the size reported by `du -b` is less than that reported by `ls -l` and that it differs for the two directories. The **entire** output of `ls -l` is identical for both directories.

There are no symlinks or system files in this directory. It's just a bunch of .jpg files (a direct copy off a camera's SD-card) and a Thumbs.db-file that Windows created for them (via samba)...

Am I missing something about how these commands should work?

(I'm running Debian Wheezy and `uname -a` outputs `Linux ... 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the `-a` switch to `ls`, I got:

```
root@...:/local/.../DCIM/100___12# du -b
5286222389      .
root@...:/local/.../DCIM/100___12# ls -al --block-size=1
total 5292867584
drwxr-xr-x 2 markus markus     12288 Aug  5  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 markus markus      4096 Aug  5  2013 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 markus markus   2167504 Aug  5  2013 IMG_0004.JPG
...
```

vs.

```
root@...:/local_old/.../DCIM/100___12# du -b
5286226485      .
root@...:/local_old/.../DCIM/100___12# ls -als --block-size=1
total 5292871680
drwxr-xr-x 2 markus markus     16384 Aug  5  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 markus markus      4096 Aug  5  2013 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 markus markus   2167504 Aug  5  2013 IMG_0004.JPG
...
```

Notice the difference in the size of the `.`-directory, which makes up exactly for the difference reported by `du -b`.

Also, it seems that the *total* reported by `ls` is actually in blocks rather than bytes. So the answer is sort-of what *@jcbermu* suggested, but backwards:

Yes, both are right, but `ls` reports the *total* size in used fs-blocks (but individual file sizes in bytes) and `du -b` reports bytes.

The difference between the source and destination that I'm seeing is caused by a difference in the size reported for `.`. Where this comes from, is another story. Probably because one reserved more directory entries at some point than the other. But at least now I'm not worried any more that something got missed in the copy process. Next step is to figure out how to tell `du` to ignore `.` and `..` in its totals and that should resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Both are right.

- *ls* shows the exact bytes of the files
- *du* is showing the disk usage, that is different because the system store the files using blocks.

You can find the block size your file system is using with this command:

```
blockdev --getbsz <partition>
```

For example:

```
blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1
```

Comment: I thought that the `-b` switch for `du` (which implies `--apparent-size`) changes that. Also, if that was the issue, the output of `du` should be **more** than that of `ls`, rather than **less**, no? And the blocksize on both, the source and target directory, is the same.

Comment: `blockdev` reports the _device's_ block size, which is not the same as a filesystem's cluster/sector size. For example, it's very common to use 4k or 8k clusters on a 512b disk.

Comment: I don't know exactly why `du` show **less** than `ls` unless you have [sparse files](http://extrabright.com/blog/2010/03/30/how-to-know-if-a-file-on-linux-is-sparse/)