# Getting `du` to ignore size of `.` and `..` entries

Tags: linux, du

Is it possible to have `du` leave out the size of the `.` and `..` entries in each directory? I can't find a specific switch for it.

Here is what **doesn't** work:

- `du -S`: doesn't change anything if there are no sub-directories
- `du --exclude=.`: excludes everything
- `du --exclude=\.`: also excludes everything
- `du --exclude=..` or `du --exclude=\.\.`: doesn't change anything (`..` is still counted)

Here is why I need this: [du and ls report different directory size?](https://superuser.com/questions/853640/du-and-ls-report-different-directory-size/853662#853662)

(I'm running Debian Wheezy and `uname -a` outputs `Linux ... 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use shell expansion to feed a list of files to du:

```
mtak@frisbee:~/bin$ du *
4   check_100k_email.sh
4   maildir_backup.sh
16  sshdict.pl
```

Or use `find` and only search for files:

```
mtak@frisbee:~/bin$ find . -type f | xargs du
16  ./sshdict.pl
4   ./check_100k_email.sh
4   ./maildir_backup.sh
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to have this recurse all subdirectories as well and give me a total at the end like `du` usually would?

Comment: ```find . -type f | xargs du -c``` should print a total, add ```tail -1``` to just print the total.